# Can I change v-switch toggle and label based on my data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

This is the code with the v-switch:

```
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      item-key="name"
      class="elevation-1"
      :footer-props="{
        showFirstLastPage: true,
        firstIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-left',
        lastIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-right',
        prevIcon: 'mdi-minus',
        nextIcon: 'mdi-plus',
           'items-per-page-text':'products per page',
      }"
    >

      <template v-slot:item.status="{ item }">
        <v-switch
          color="success"
          :model-value="item.status"
          :label="item.status ? 'Delicious' : 'Nope'"
        ></v-switch>
      </template>
    
    </v-data-table>
```

and this is my mockup data

```
headers: [
        { text: 'Order', value: 'order'},
        { text: 'Name', value: 'name'},
        { text: 'Status', value: 'status'},
      ],
      
desserts: [
        {
          order: '1',
          name: 'Cake',
          status: true
        },
        {
          order: '2',
          name: 'Chocolate',
          status: false
        },
      ],
```

I tried to make the v-switch toggle display on or off base on the status data in desserts but it didn't work.

When status in desserts in true I want the v-switch toggle is on and display the label "Delicious" in the table and when status in desserts in false I want the v-switch toggle is off and display the label "Nope" in table

For example first data in desserts, it should display v-switch toggle on with label Delicious on table column and when user toggle the v-switch, the label should change to Nope.

Is there a way to do it? I have tried many ways but nothing work at all.
Thank you.

Comment: What Vue library do you use? It looks live you use Vuetify. Then what version of it?

Comment: @Tolbxela Yes, it is Vuetify. "nuxt": "^2.15.8", "vue": "^2.7.10", "vuetify": "^2.6.10"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `vuejs2` tag I assume Vuetify 2 is being used here *but* you're probably reading the Vuetify 3 docs because the `modelValue` property of `<v-switch>` is Vuetify 3 only.  [Here are the Vuetify 2 docs](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/switches/). With Vuetify 2 you should either use

#### v-model (two-way binding)

```html
<v-switch 
  color="success" 
  v-model="item.status" 
  :label="item.status ? 'Delicious' : 'Nope'"
></v-switch>
```

This way the v-switch initial value will be the same as `dessert.status` and toggling the v-switch also updates `dessert.status` so they're always synced.

#### input-value (one-way binding)

```html
<v-switch
  color="success"
  :input-value="item.status"
  :label="item.status ? 'Delicious' : 'Nope'"
  @change="toggleMethod"
></v-switch>
```

This way the switch uses `dessert.status` for it's initial value but they will not stay synced if either are changed. Usually also means the use of the `@change` event handler to do something based on the switch's new value.

Comment: omg, Thanks a lot. You are right! I read the Vuetify 3 doc T.T